# Como pesquisar por usuários no banco de dados sem select option

Tags: php

Bom pessoal sempre achei ruim um metodo que utilizo para pesquisar usuários no banco de dados em um select option, quando tenho muitos registros a página demora a carregar e so tende a piorar, alguem tem alguma ideia de como posso reestruturar minha busca por usuario trazendo atraves de nomes os usuarios similares e não digitando exatamente o nome completo?

código clientes.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['apagar']) && $_GET['apagar'] == 'excluir') {
        $deleta = mysql_query("DELETE FROM t_cadclientes WHERE Ficha = '$_GET[id]'");
    if($deleta == '1'){
        echo "Cliente deletado com sucesso !";
    echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='2;URL=clientes.php'>";
    }else{
        echo "Erro ao deletar, favor tente novamente !";
}
}
?>
<div id="painelclientes">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Ficha, Snome FROM t_cadclientes ORDER BY Ficha ASC, Snome ASC";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql)
            or die (mysql_error());
if(@mysql_num_rows($resultado) == 0)
            echo ("Cliente não encontrado(a) !");
?>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method"post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div align="center">
  <table border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td><label>
          <select name="id" id="id">
            <option value="-1" selected="selected">Selecione um cliente</option>
            <?php 
    while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        $id = $linha[0];
        $Snome = $linha[1];
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $Snome;  ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
          </select>
          </label></td>
          <tr>
        <label>
          <input type="hidden" name="apagar" value="excluir" />
          <input type=image src="../images/excluirOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/excluir.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/excluirOver.png'" title="Excluir" style="border:0;" name="excluir" id="excluir" value="Excluir" />
          <input type=image src="../images/editarOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/editar.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/editarOver.png'" title="Editar" style="border:0;" name="Alterar" id="Alterar" value="Alterar" formaction="editar_clientes.php" />
          <input type=image src="../images/vendas_crediarioOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/vendas_crediario.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/vendas_crediarioOver.png'" title="Venda Crediário" style="border:0;" name="vendas_crediario" id="vendas_crediario" value="vendas_crediario" formaction="vendas_crediario.php" />
          <input type=image src="../images/imprimirOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/imprimir.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/imprimirOver.png'" title="Imprimir" style="border:0;" name="Imprimir" id="Imprimir" value="Imprimir"  formaction="imprimir_clientes.php" />
          <input type=image src="../images/cadastrarOver.png" onMouseOver="this.src='../images/cadastrar.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/cadastrarOver.png'" title="Cadastrar" style="border:0;" name="cadastrar" id="cadastrar" value="cadastrar"  formaction="cadastro_clientes.php" />
          </label>
      </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer dizer com "a página demora a carregar"? quantas entradas tem no SQL? a busca parece bem simples.

Comment: Entro na página e a mesma fica travada até carregador todos os usuários no meu select, tenho mais de 2.000 usuários... preciso elaborar um algorítimo de busca pelo nome do usuário e ao mesmo tempo exibindo sugestões de nomes conforme vou digitando na busca

Comment: Então o melhor é ter um search que vai buscar info via ajax à medida que escreve. Tipo Google.

Comment: O caso que você citou de como trazer através de nomes os usuários similares sem digitar todo o nome você pode utilizar o LIKE do SELECT se bem entendi, ex: `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo LIKE '%Rafa%' `Neste caso busca por registros no banco que comecem, terminem ou contenham Rafa

Comment: Agora, para que esta sugestão de autocompletar aconteça de forma automática conforme o usuário digita você necessitará utilizar AJAX ou Jquery, tem um plugin legal que dá pra fazer isso: http://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: @TiagoBoeing Muito Obrigado! Verifiquei o link do autocomplete, achei muito bacana mas tem bastante conteúdo que não entendi muito bem, tens como exemplificar de como posso utilizar esta jquery autocomplete ?

Comment: Você pode utilizá-lo para substituir campos `<select>` por exemplo. O usuário começa digitando alguns valores e em tempo real o autocomplete filtra os resultados em uma lista, no exemplo elas estão no arquivo `countries.js` (https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/scripts/countries.js). Você pode baixar o projeto oficial no github, inclusive com alguns modelos, aparentemente é fácil de editar. https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Comment: Existem outros plugins autocomplete com AJAX, jQuery, etc. Basta dar uma pesquisada. Coloquei este plugin como exemplo porque achei interessante e que talvez ele possa satisfazer suas necessidades de acordo com a pergunta efetuada. Fico feliz se tiver ajudado!

Comment: @TiagoBoeing ajudou muito, obrigado mesmo, consegui importar para meu código, mas estou perdido em como buscar o id e nome dos clientes no meu banco de dados ao inves da região que esta no arquivo countries.js, consegues me ajudar ??

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar este plugin jquery([http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput][1]) da seguinte forma:

Incluir jQuery e o plugin no head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfiles/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourfiles/token-input.css" />
```

e iniciar assim:

```
<input type="text" name="blah" id="user-input">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#user-input").tokenInput("/clientes-ajax.php");
});
</script>
```

o arquivo clientes-ajax.php seria algo assim para retornar :

```
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '{$q}%'", $db);  

//Create an array
$json_response = array();
$row_array = array();

while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
   $row_array['id']= [$linha[0];
   $row_array['name']= [$linha[1];

   //push the values in the array
   array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

Comment: entendi sua ideia, tentei implementar mas estou tendo erros de compilação, não entendi muito bem o funcionário, podes me explicar novamente? obrigado!